# Unity Engine binding redirection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assemblies

I am using Unity Engine and the Nuget for Unity plugin. In our project we use multiple nuget plugins that refer to Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.2. We also use Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime which refers to an older version of Newtonsoft.Json (10.0.3). This last plugin however always outputs an error in the Editor :

> Unloading broken assembly
>   Assets/Packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.2.3.20/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll,
>   this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime

For some reason, we are still able to use classes from that library, but it causes issues when we try to use reflection.

For example:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .ToArray();
```

This throws a ReflectionTypeLoadException once it tries to call `GetTypes()` on the Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime assembly. The LoaderExceptions associated with the exception are all Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0.0. I bet it's because we already use version 12 and it can't load the same assemblies for different versions.

Now I wanted to use something like `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.3.0" newVersion="12.0.2.0"/>` but that doesn't seem to be possible in Unity. Is there something similar I can do? Or can I maybe fix my problem another way?

P.S. I have temporarily fixed it by ignoring the assembly from the Linq query since we don't need it, but I don't like errors in my console and would like to solve the underlying cause.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sadly we have not found a way to resolve this issue other than by getting rid of our dependency on Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.

We also now rely on the Json.NET plugin distributed by Unity themselves.